# Merging iqy files with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merging-data

currently I extracted data from sharepoint and have .iqy files that I can open with excel. There are about 30 files and I am trying to merge all the information into one .iqy file or excel file with python.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

files = []
for file in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\CHI86786\\Downloads"):
    files.append(file)

excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in files]
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None, index_col=None) for x in excels]

frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

combined = pd.concat(frames)
combined.to_excel("SPmerged.iqy", header=False, index=False)
```

took a same approach as if I would merge excel files. but I keep getting an error that reads `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'desktop.ini'`

EDIT

more of the error message

```
File "C:\Users\CHI\source\repos\MergingExcel\MergingExcel\MergingExcel.py", line 8, in <module>
    excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in files] #reads names in
  File "C:\Users\CHI86786\source\repos\MergingExcel\MergingExcel\MergingExcel.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in files] #reads names in
  File "C:\Users\CHI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "C:\Users\CHI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'desktop.ini'
```

Comment: The error should be more than that, and should tell you where the problem is in your code.

Comment: I mean it does say where its at but it points at the module or a built in python script (i added more of the error to the original posti) so im not sure where `'desktop.ini'` is coming from

Comment: FYI, I'd be quite surprised if pd.ExcelFile will handle iqy files, so I don't think this entire approach is going to work.

Comment: FYI, just paste your code into the text box, highlight it, and press Cmd-K (or Ctrl-K on Windows I guess) to indent it for code display. Another option is to put three backticks on a line, paste your content, and then put three more backticks on a separate line. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You're right it's an unsupported format. @DSM

Comment: Thanks @Miken32 I'll try that for when I put code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to act on every file in `C:\Users\CHI86786\Downloads`, including system files like "desktop.ini".

Instead, try restricting it to the files you're interested in using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\CHI86786\\Downloads\\*.iqy")
```

Comment: Yup that worked, and showed me that it was an unsupported format. Figured that these files are being opened with excel that I'd be able to take this approach.

Comment: Didn't know what an IQY file was, thought maybe it was just a CSV file with a proprietary extension or something.

Comment: it is an internet query file. Yeah took me sometime to see find out what it was. I'm going to try and convert them to xlsx and give you guys an update